# change multiple prices with checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to create a pricing table where monthly price is given and a checkbox from where you can toggle between monthly and annually prices. I have 8 price cards with different prices. First I got the classes and ids of the checkbox and price labels and with js function I'm trying to change the prices. But when I check the first time the prices are multiplying but when unchecked, the prices do not return to original. And later I'm getting NaN values.

**html**

```
             <label class="switch">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="price-checkbox"
                  onclick="changePrice('price-checkbox', 'price');"
                />
                <span class="slider round"></span>
              </label>

            <div class="card text-center">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase fw-bold mb-3">Basic</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle my-2">
                  <span class="price fs-4 fw-bold">540.00</span> per month
                </h6>
                <p class="card-text my-4">50,000 Minutes- SIP</p>
                <p class="card-text mb-4">50,000 minutes monthly renewal</p>
                <div class="btn-container">
                  <button class="btn" type="button">Purchase Now</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-center">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase fw-bold mb-3">ADVANCED</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle my-2">
                  <span class="price fs-4 fw-bold">990.00</span> per month
                </h6>
                <p class="card-text my-4">50,000 Minutes- SIP</p>
                <p class="card-text mb-4">50,000 minutes monthly renewal</p>
                <div class="btn-container">
                  <button class="btn" type="button">Purchase Now</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-center">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase fw-bold mb-3">Premium</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle my-2">
                  <span class="price fs-4 fw-bold">2025.00</span> per month
                </h6>
                <p class="card-text my-4">50,000 Minutes- SIP</p>
                <p class="card-text mb-4">50,000 minutes monthly renewal</p>
                <div class="btn-container">
                  <button class="btn" type="button">Purchase Now</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**JS**

```
function changePrice(id, label) {
  const chkbox = document.getElementById(id);
  const price = document.getElementsByClassName(label);
  let prevPrice = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
    console.log(parseFloat(price[i].innerHTML));
    prevPrice.push(parseFloat(price[i].innerHTML));
  }

  if (chkbox.checked) {
    for (let i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
      price[i].innerHTML = parseFloat(price[i].innerHTML) * 12;
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
      price[i].innerHTML = prevPrice[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `prevPrice` should be persistent outside of the `changePrice` function. Or maybe you could change `price[i].innerHTML = prevPrice[i];` to `price[i].innerHTML = parseFloat(price[i].innerHTML) / 12;`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thanks...the division technique works...I totally forgot to persist the prevPrice

Comment: @JohnnyMopp also how do you get comma separated thousands in this.. I looked up prev answers and added a separate function for this where I'm passing the float value..but it doesn't change